# Bootstrap Fluid grid system Issue Opera 11.64

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<!-- html -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12 slider">Text 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span8 main">
             Text  2
        </div>
        <div class="span4 login">
             Text  3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

/* CSS */
.login, .main {
    border: 1px solid #aeaeae;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.slider {
    height: 120px;
    border: 1px solid #aeaeae;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-image: url(../Images/divFonWithoutBorder.png);
}
```

**Opera**

[image: My issue]

[image: On bootstrap documentation page]

**In other browser**

[image: In other browser]

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is a bug in Opera where fractional percentages are rounded down to the closest integral percentage, e.g. 5.98% becomes 5%. As far as I know Opera has never handled this properly.

I don't know a good solution to this. One option is to accept it (while the bug remains). As the percentages are rounded down, the result should only be aesthetically unpleasant, there won't be problems where rows spill over to two rows. Another option is to refrain from using the fluid grid system.

I've opened a bug at Opera for this, with the number DSK-364769 (there is no way to follow progress, however).